# Text to speech Library for Android and iPhone both

Tags: android, iphone, ios, objective-c

I m going to work on an text to speech application which will be in both android and iphone. I found very good threads on stackoverflow for TTS libraries in iphone.

My question is : should i need to use same library for both iphone and android ?

If yes are there any same library provider for both iPhone and Android ? I just want to be sure that the both the apps dont behave so different to each other if I am going to use different libaray , thats why I am curious to find a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with **Flite-TTS-Engine** which is available and compatible with both **iOS and Android**.

You can find **Android** [Flite-TTS-Engine here](https://github.com/happyalu/Flite-TTS-Engine-for-Android/blob/master/jni/tts/tts.h)

You can find **iOS** [Flite-TTS-Engine here](https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/src/a6502c779cd3/flite-1.4-iphone/)

Answer (score 1):

**For iOS**

**Text To Speech(TTS)**

https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/src
https://github.com/todoroo/iPhone-Speech-To-Text
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/TTS
https://github.com/macdonst/TTS
http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/10/12/First-test-of-PhoneGap-Plugins
http://en.usenet.digipedia.org/thread/12992/27474/ 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/phonegap/JSBV8zfbXZ0/JqiLM5HdTF4J
http://phonegap.com/blog/2012/09/

This linke may be helpful for you :)

Comment: Yes you are right. but My question is : should i need to use same library for both iphone and android ?